# How to get full path of image while uploading image

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to upload image but it not take fill path of image. It take only file name with extension.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("#sok").on('click',function(e){
                //alert("Ok");
                e.preventDefault();
                var imf = $("#FoodieProfileImage").val();
                alert(imf);
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'Image.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: imf,
                    async: false,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function () {
                      //alert(returndata);
                    //  $("#target").html(data);
                    },
                    error: function(){

                    }
                }); 

            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="editUserForm" method="post" action="Image.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Profile Image</label>            
                <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="FoodieProfileImage" id="FoodieProfileImage"/>             

            </div>
        </form>
        <div id="target"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="button" id="sok" value="ok"/>
        </div>
    </html>
```

And php script like as:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_FILES["FoodieProfileImage"]["name"]) && $_FILES["FoodieProfileImage"]["size"] > 0) {

//Set upload path
$uploadPath =  "images/";
echo $uploadPath;//print_r();
exit();
//Check for is directoty exist ot not, if not then create new directoty
if (!is_dir($uploadPath)) {
    mkdir($uploadPath);
     chmod($uploadPath, 0755);
}
if(isset($_FILES["FoodieProfileImage"]['name'])) {
    $fileName = $_FILES["FoodieProfileImage"]["name"];
    //$fileName = realpath($fileName);
    //print_r(S_FILES);exit();
    //$newUserDetail['profileImage'] = $fileName;
    //pathinfo - Is a function that seperates file name, extension, basename

    $path_parts = pathinfo($fileName);

    $fileName = str_replace(" " , "_", strtolower($path_parts['filename'])); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.
    $fileName = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $fileName); // Removes special chars.
    $fileName .= 'Foodie'.$userId ;

    //Create new file name
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['FoodieProfileImage']["tmp_name"], $uploadPath . $fileName . '.' . $path_parts['extension']);

    //Get Path for Uploaded File
    $newUserDetail['profileImage'] = $uploadPath . $fileName. '.' . $path_parts['extension'];
    //print_r($newUserDetail['profileImage']);exit();
    //Get page image detail by page id
}

}
?>
```

Comment: Why should an arbitrary webserver know details about the client's file system? That's not necessary for the fulfillment of its task, so the client will only transmit the file contents itself.

Comment: ok.. I want to show preview of Image while uploading Image so that's why I am taking full path of Image and trying to set to #target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server itself can only display data which it has got, and even if it'd know about the file path, it won't be able to access it (since you receive your data by an HTTP request, not by any kind of pulling or so).

What can probably solve your task is to use the [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) API via JavaScript and implement some logic to create a thumbnail on the client side while uploading your image at the same time.